# Building up a dictionary/hash with lists

Tags: ansible

I am attempting to build a dictionary but cannot grasp how jinja2 interpolates variables.

I want to set a specific item in the array (for example item[0]) to a specific key-value dictionary item.

```
- set_fact: 
    nodes: 
      - node1
      - node2 

- set_fact:
    list_one: 
      - f-one
      - f-two 

- set_fact: 
    list_two:
      - n-one
      - n-two
```

what I want:

```
- set_fact: 
    **node_dict:
      node1:
        labels:
          f-one: n-one
      node2:
        labels: 
          f-two: n-two**
```

When I run :

```
- name: check loop1
  debug:
   msg: '{{item[0]}} - {{item[1]}} - {{ item[2]}} '
  with_nested:
    - '{{ nodes }}'
    - '{{ list_one }}'
    - '{{ list_two }}'
```

`item` variable is availble. But doing this:

```
- set_fact: 
    final:
      '{{item[0]}}':
        labels:
          "{{item[1] }}" : "{{item[2]}}"
    with_nested:
      - '{{ nodes }}'
      - '{{ list_one }}'
      - '{{ list_two }}'
```

results in an error.

Can someone explain why? How do I end up with my desired result?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Although your last piece of code above does not meet your requirement, It's perfectly valid: I'm not getting any error when running it.
2. As your are using it right now, `set_fact` is overwriting your `final` variable on each loop. To append element to a dict like your are trying to do,  you need to initialize the var to an empty dict and [combine](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_filters.html#combining-hashes-dictionaries) it with the values you are calculating for each iteration. Since your calculated values are a dict themselves, you will need to use `recursive=True` if you have to write expressions deep inside the dict.
3. If I take into account your original data and your expected result, you want to relate the *Nth* element of each lists together. This is not what `nested` does (loop over `nodes` with a sub-loop on `list_one` sub-sub-loop on `list_two`....). In your case, you simply need to loop over an index of the length of your lists and combine the elements of same index together. My take below.

```
---
- name: test for SO
  hosts: localhost

  vars:
    nodes:
      - node1
      - node2
    list_one:
      - f-one
      - f-two
    list_two:
      - n-one
      - n-two

  tasks:
    - name: Make my config
      set_fact:
        final: >-
          {{
            final
            | default({})
            | combine ({
                nodes[item]: {
                  'labels': {
                    list_one[item]: list_two[item]
                  }
                }
              }, recursive=True)
          }}
      loop: "{{ range(nodes | length) | list }}"

    - name: debug
      debug:
        var: final
```

which gives the following result

```sh
$ ansible-playbook test.yml 

PLAY [test for SO] ******************************************************************

TASK [Gathering Facts] **************************************************************
ok: [localhost]

TASK [Make my config] ***************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => (item=0)
ok: [localhost] => (item=1)

TASK [debug] ************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "final": {
        "node1": {
            "labels": {
                "f-one": "n-one"
            }
        },
        "node2": {
            "labels": {
                "f-two": "n-two"
            }
        }
    }
}

PLAY RECAP **************************************************************************
localhost                  : ok=3    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0
```

**Edit**: The same result can be acheived using the [zip filter](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_filters.html#zip-and-zip-longest-filters) (which I (re)discovered today [reading an other contribution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56023982/9401096)).

```
    - name: Make my config
       set_fact:
         final: >-
           {{
             final
             | default({})
             | combine ({
                 item.0: {
                   'labels': {
                     item.1: item.2
                   }
                 }
               }, recursive=True)
           }}
       loop: "{{ nodes | zip(list_one, list_two) | list }}"
```

Comment: Thank you SO MUCH for providing an explanation to the solution.

Comment: Glad I could help.

Comment: How do I ensure that this runs only once for every nodes in a group? I am running into a situation whereby it runs twice for each node in the group thus overwriting the labels variable. ** Just thought to use `run_once: true`. Will test**

Answer (score 1):

(update)

Use Jinja template

```yaml
  node_dict: |
    {% filter from_yaml %}
    {% for n,k,v in nodes|zip(list_one)|zip(list_two)|map('flatten') %}
    {{ n }}: {label: { {{ k }}: {{ v }} }}
    {% endfor %}
    {% endfilter %}
```

gives what you want

```yaml
  node_dict:
    node1:
      label:
        f-one: n-one
    node2:
      label:
        f-two: n-two
```

---

Example of a complete playbook for testing

```yaml
- hosts: localhost
  
  vars:

    nodes: [node1, node2]
    list_one: [f-one, f-two]
    list_two: [n-one, n-two]

    node_dict: |
      {% filter from_yaml %}
      {% for n,k,v in nodes|zip(list_one)|zip(list_two)|map('flatten') %}
      {{ n }}: {label: { {{ k }}: {{ v }} }}
      {% endfor %}
      {% endfilter %}

  tasks:

    - debug:
        var: node_dict
```

---

(origin)

The next option would be to create a list of labels

```yaml
    - set_fact:
        my_labels: "{{ my_labels|d([]) +
                       [{list_one[my_idx]:list_two[my_idx]}] }}"
      loop: "{{ nodes }}"
      loop_control:
        index_var: my_idx
```

gives

```yaml
  my_labels:
  - f-one: n-one
  - f-two: n-two
```

and then combine the dictionary

```yaml
    - set_fact:
        node_dict: "{{ node_dict|d({})|
                       combine({item:{'labels':my_labels[my_idx]}}) }}"
      loop: "{{ nodes }}"
      loop_control:
        index_var: my_idx
```

gives the same result

```yaml
  node_dict:
    node1:
      labels:
        f-one: n-one
    node2:
      labels:
        f-two: n-two
```

---

Example of a complete playbook for testing

```yaml
- hosts: localhost
  
  vars:

    nodes: [node1, node2]
    list_one: [f-one, f-two]
    list_two: [n-one, n-two]

  tasks:

    - set_fact:
        my_labels: "{{ my_labels|d([]) +
                       [{list_one[my_idx]:list_two[my_idx]}] }}"
      loop: "{{ nodes }}"
      loop_control:
        index_var: my_idx

    - set_fact:
        node_dict: "{{ node_dict|d({})|
                       combine({item:{'labels':my_labels[my_idx]}}) }}"
      loop: "{{ nodes }}"
      loop_control:
        index_var: my_idx

    - debug:
        var: my_labels
    - debug:
        var: node_dict
```